# Pointer addresses of Python Lists and Matrix when reversing

Tags: python, list, pointers, matrix, reverse

I am trying to understand how Python matrices are implemented as compared to Java/C style 2D arrays.

Specifically the problem I am facing is this:

Given a matrix (list of lists), I am asked to reverse the individual lists in the matrix in-place. I came up with the following code:

```
CODE 1
------

def flip(matrix):
    for list in matrix:
        list=list[::-1]

matrix=[[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]
flip(matrix)
print(matrix) # Outputs "[[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]" i.e. does not reverse
```

If I modify the code a bit,

```
CODE 2
------

def flip(matrix):
    for list in matrix:
        list.reverse()

matrix=[[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]
flip(matrix)
print(matrix) # Outputs "[[0,0,1],[1,0,0]]" i.e. works correctly this time
```

I know that `list.reverse()` does in-place operation and `list[::-1]` creates a shallow copy. However in `CODE 1`, I am assigning the address of the shallow copy to the same variable (`list`) only. So the variable `matrix` should effectively get changed. Because the variable matrix[i] `is` the variable list. So if `list` gets modified, so should `matrix`.

To illustrate my previous point, the following code is provided:

```
CODE 3
------

def test(matrix):
    for i, list in enumerate(matrix):
        print(matrix[i] is list)

matrix=[[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]
test(matrix) # Outputs "True True"
```

If `matrix[i] is list`, then changing `list` means changing `matrix[i]` and changing `matrix[i]` means changing `matrix`.

If I modify `CODE 1` so that instead of `list` being assigned the address of the newly created reversed list, `matrix[i]` be assigned that address, then surprisingly it works!

```
CODE 4
------

def flip(matrix):
    for i, list in enumerate(matrix):
        # Instead of  list=list[::-1]
        matrix[i]=list[::-1] 

matrix=[[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]
flip(matrix)
print(matrix) # Correctly Outputs [[0,0,1], [1,0,0]]
```

I would like an explanation why `CODE 1` does not work and why `CODE 4` works.

Comment: If you tried that with a Java 2D array, it wouldn't have worked either.

Answer (score 2):

The first time through the loop, `list` is just a name for `matrix[0]`.

Mutating the object that `list` names, as in CODE 2, obviously mutates the object that `matrix[0]` names, because they're naming the same object.

But just rebinding `list` to some different object, as in CODE 1, doesn't change `matrix[0]` in any way. If you think about it, that makes sense. After all, the next time through the loop, `list` is going to get rebound to `matrix[1]`, and you certainly wouldn't want that to change what's in `matrix[0]`, right?

In C terms (and this is literally true, if you're using the normal CPython implementation), being names for the same object means being pointers to the same object. If `list` is a `List *`, assigning to `list` doesn't do anything to whatever was in `*list`.

So, why does CODE 4 work? Well, in code 4, you're still not mutating the list—but you're rebinding `matrix[0]`, instead of `list`, and of course that rebinds `matrix[0]`.

I'm guessing that, despite talking about "Java/C", you're really thinking in C++ terms. In C++, `=` is an operator, which can be overloaded. Plus, you don't just have pointers, but references, which sort of magically work without needing to explicitly dereference them. So, if `list` is a reference to a list object, rather than a pointer, `list =` isn't changing it into a reference to another list object, it's calling a special method, `ListType::operator=`. That's actually pretty weird. There's nothing like that in Java. or C. any more than there is in Python.

---

For more detail on what happens under the covers:

If you want to think of it in C terms, the actual C API used by the main (CPython) implementation may make things clear here.

- Your function's locals are just an array of pointers to Python objects. That `matrix` is `locals[0]`, `list` is `locals[1]`, etc.
- What's in `*locals[0]` is a `PyListObject` struct, which contains, among other things, a pointer to an array of Python objects. Each of which is pointing to another `PyListObject` struct. But inside those inner lists' arrays are pointers to `PyLongObject` structs, which just hold numbers.
- The `for` loop is a bit more complicated than this, but pretend it's just doing `locals[1] = (*locals[0]).elements[0]`, then `locals[1] = (*locals[0]).elements[1]`, etc.
- So, assigning to `list` is just changing `locals[1]`, not `*locals[1]`, and therefore it's not changing `*locals[0].elements[0]`.
- But assigning to `*locals[0].elements[0]` is a different story.
- And so is calling the `reverse` method. When you do that, `self` just ends up as yet another pointer to the same object, but its implementation mutates things on `*self`.

Comment: So you mean to say that list and matrix[0] are different variables and they occupy different addresses in memory?

Comment: @SounakBhattacharya Not _quite_, but it’s a good enough analogy for people who understand C semantics and are confused by Python. Really, `list` is a name that gets converted to an index in a locals array, and `matrix[0]` is a complex target that actually assigns via `matrix.__setitem__`, so neither one is really a variable in C terms. But for our purposes, yes, they act like two separate pointer variables pointing to the same thing.